# Does every font installed in the computer show up when used in HTML?

Tags: html

I was trying the `<font>` tag...

```
<html>
<font face="papyrus" size="20"> This is a font demo! </font>
</html>
```

It show up in the Papyrus font... But when I use some other fonts... They don't show up... What's the reason for this??

Comment: Those fonts are installed on the _client_ system, are they?

Comment: Other fonts that are installed in the system. Fonts like Arial and Times New Roman work but not the others...

Comment: Many don't... For example, this: http://www.dafont.com/street-cred.font

Answer (score 3):

When an element on a web page is rendered, its CSS is checked and the browser attempts to apply the given style to it. Fonts are specified by the CSS `font-family` attribute. (You should not use the `<font>` tag.) The browser will look at the fonts specified in the attribute, and check if the current system environment contains them. For example:

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
```

The browser will attempt to display the first font on the list and descend one by one if it does not support a given font until it finds one that it does. Such declarations should always end with one of the following generic families:

- Serif
- Sans-Serif
- Monospace
- Cursive
- Fantasy

As these are aliases for default fonts which will always be displayable by the browser.

If you wish to guarantee that a page displays a given font, you can use the CSS3 @font-face directive. This allows you to store a font on your server and have it loaded by the client application when your page is accessed.

As for formats, TrueType and OpenType are common and widely-available, but have been superseded by the WOFF format (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face). WOFF is an open format and is in the process of being standardized by the W3C (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format).

One final word: Not all fonts are free and open. Be careful that you are not sharing a proprietary font with the @font-face directive. You can specify proprietary fonts with CSS, because they will only be loaded on machines which have them (hopefully legally) installed, but @font-face shares the font with all users, and as such you must have the rights to do so before using the font in this way. Google Web Fonts is a great place to start if you are looking for fonts that are free to use in this manner http://www.google.com/webfonts.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<font face=...>` in HTML, or its more modern counterpart `font-family: ...` in CSS, lets you use the fonts that have been installed in the computer where the page is viewed.

So for example, if you have downloaded the zipped package for Street Cred from http://www.dafont.com/street-cred.font and unzipped and installed the font, then `<font face="Street Cred">Hello world</font>` shows the text in that font.

If you haven’t done that, it won’t work, since that font is hardly pre-installed in any computer.

Sometimes it is not obvious which font *name* should be used. This has not been standardized, but normally browsers recognize the font family name as defined in the font itself (in the names table). This need not coincide with the name of the font file.

To check out which fonts are installed in a computer, you can use services like the following:

My [font list viewer](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/listfonts1.html) (works in IE only)

[Getting a List of Installed Fonts with Flash and Javascript](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/526/getting-a-list-of-installed-fonts-with-flash-and-javascript/)

[Font list example](http://hasseg.org/stuff/fontList/example.html) (requires Flash)

Comment: Thank you, sir! My wrong was... Whenever I used a font... I checked it's name in the installed fonts and it showed "Butterbelly Regular" and I gave the same name... When I remover the "regular" out of it, it worked!

Answer (score -1):

> **font tag does not supported in HTML5.** this may first Reason for not support.
>
> use **font-family** attribute in css instead.

*Anybody can refer : w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp*

Comment: Wrong. HTML5 requires support to `font` markup, and even if it did not, browsers would still support it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5.

Comment: @ BoltClock,@  Jukka K. Korpela, you can refer w3schools for support of font tag in html5, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: @Sandip, I prefer consulting the most authoritative information, such as the W3C HTML5 material, rather than w3schools, known to be very unreliable, see http://w3fools.com

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : Thanks Mate, next time I'll take care of that.